# iphone sdk with commandline

Tags: objective-c

i try to call command line or shellscript in objective C to use with iphone application
but it not work
i use system("ls"); 
or
NSString *cmd = @"ls";
system([cmd UTF8String]);
or fopen 
but it's no respond 
please help me 
i want to use shell script to scp callog to server

Comment: This is for jailbroken devices, right?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of the `NSTask` class.

Comment: i think NSTask can't use with iphone sdk             
Apple has removed the NSTask from the Foundations Framework in the iPhone